# Access SQL - Return unique combinations in field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with data stored vertically, I have shown a simplified example below which has a record for each city a customer has lived in:

```
| CUSTOMER  |     CITY      | 
------------------------------
|   John    |    London     |  
|   John    |    Manchester | 
|   Sarah   |    Cardiff    |  
|   Sarah   |    Edinburgh  |  
|   Sarah   |    Liverpool  | 
|   Craig   |    Manchester | 
|   Craig   |    London     |
```

I am trying to come up with an SQL query that will return all unique combinations of cities so in the example above, John and Craig have both lived in London and Manchester but Sarah has lived in different cities (Cardiff, Edinburgh and Liverpool) so I would like an output as below (which can handle any amount of cities)

```
|  CITY1    |     CITY2     |      CITY3   | 
--------------------------------------------
|   London  |    Manchester |              |
|   Cardiff |    Edinburgh  |  Liverpool   |
```

I have tried using a crosstab query to view the data horizontally like this:

```
TRANSFORM Max(City)
SELECT Customer
FROM tblCities
GROUP BY Customer
PIVOT City
```

but it is just returning a field for all cities for every customer. Does anyone know if this is possible using SQL?

p.s Ideally it will ignore the order of cities

Comment: Wbat happens if a person has lived in only one city, or three cities?

Comment: Good question, I expect the best way would be to have enough columns for the person with the most cities and anyone with less than that would just have the first however many columns populated?

Comment: use an outer select to distinct your transform ?`Select distinct * from (TRANSFORM Max(City)
SELECT Customer
FROM tblCities
GROUP BY Customer
PIVOT City) B` ?

Comment: Hi xQbert, I have tried as suggested but am getting an error message "Syntax error in FROM clause"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a nice challenge! The query below gets the groupings per customer. It doesn't discard the duplicates where multiple customers have lived in the same combination of cities ... I'll let you or others find a way to handle that.

```
TRANSFORM Min(OrderedList.City) AS MinOfCity
SELECT OrderedList.Customer
FROM (SELECT CustomerCities.Customer, CustomerCities.City, Count(1) AS CityNo
FROM CustomerCities INNER JOIN CustomerCities AS CustomerCities_1 ON CustomerCities.Customer = CustomerCities_1.Customer
WHERE (((CustomerCities.City)>=[CustomerCities_1].[City]))
GROUP BY CustomerCities.Customer, CustomerCities.City) OrderedList
GROUP BY OrderedList.Customer
PIVOT "CITY" & [CityNo];
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks Steve. I'm sure I can remove the duplicates from here, this is a great help

Comment: If I think of a nice way to do it, I'll update my answer, but to begin you could simply save that code as one query and then write a second query which does a "select distinct" without including the customer field. That's not nice though, since you'd effectivtly be "hard coding" the number of cities into that outer query ... though it would be easy to adjust as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct c1.city, c2.city
from tblCities as c1 inner join
     tblCities as c2
     on c1.customer = c2.customer and c1.city < c2.city;
```

This returns all pairs of cities that appear for any single customer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My apologies, I didn't explain very well but it is not always just pairs but can be any number of cities. I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which might work assuming each customer is only associated with two cities:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.city_1, t.city_2
FROM
(
    SELECT MIN(CITY) AS city_1, MAX(CITY) AS city_2
    FROM tblCities
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My apologies, I didn't explain very well but it is not always just pairs but can be any number of cities. I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer